# AmCharts4 Value does not exist

Tags: amcharts4

I have got a chart which I have been working quite some time now. Lately, I noticed the following error in the console:
[image]

This error spams my console and funny enought, everything works perfectly fine. I still want to get rid of it, however. Things I have noticed:

- After building the chart, I have the error roughtly 10 times in the console
- It does not matter If my chart has data or not, it will always be there, spamming the console
- When I do a mouseover, the error is created many many more times
- Everything works perfectly fine: my chart is there, I see the bubbles on mouse over, etc.

Because the error log does not tell me anything, I really do not know what to do or where to start looking.

Providing a snippet is very difficult and time consuming, as the different parts of the code are split up in three files. I will do so however, if I do not manage to solve it any time soon.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that a colleague removed the exportButton and when AmCharts tried to tie the exporting functionality to this button, it threw this error. However, I do not understand why such an obvious error would produce such an ambigous error log.